# Python function logic returning wrong value

Tags: python, function, if-statement

This is my program. The problem is if I only give the food value, the function return the wrong part. But if I give both value works fine

```
x = str(input())
y = str(input())

def food(x,y = "Mohakhali"):
    if x == "BBQ Chicken Cheese Burger" and y == "Mohakhali":
        print(250+(250*0.08)+40)
    elif x == "BBQ Chicken Cheese Burger" and y != "Mohakhali":
        print(250+(250*0.08)+60)
    elif x =="Beef Burger" and y =="Mohakhali":
        print(170+(170*0.08)+40)
    elif x =="Beef Burger" and y !="Mohakhali": #for only Beef Burger function prints this.
        print(170+(170*0.08)+60)
    elif x =="Nana Drums" and y =="Mohakhali":
        print(200+(200*0.08)+40)
    elif x =="Nana Drums" and y !="Mohakhali":
        print(200+(200*0.08)+60)
    else:
        print("We dont sell that")
(food(x,y))
```

Comment: Yes, that's because you are telling python to take default value of `Mohakhali` to variable `y` in case it's not given

Comment: that is the problem. if i only give x -> Beef Burger . I should get the value 223.6 same as if I had given the y value->Mohakhali , but I am  getting 243.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you enter no value for `y` it will become empty string. Though it's an empty string, it will still get passed to the function as `y=""`.

```
x = str(input())
y = str(input())

def food(x,y = "Mohakhali"):
    if x == "BBQ Chicken Cheese Burger" and y == "Mohakhali":
        print(250+(250*0.08)+40)
    elif x == "BBQ Chicken Cheese Burger" and y != "Mohakhali":
        print(250+(250*0.08)+60)
    elif x =="Beef Burger" and y =="Mohakhali":
        print(170+(170*0.08)+40)
    elif x =="Beef Burger" and y !="Mohakhali": #for only Beef Burger function prints this.
        print(170+(170*0.08)+60)
    elif x =="Nana Drums" and y =="Mohakhali":
        print(200+(200*0.08)+40)
    elif x =="Nana Drums" and y !="Mohakhali":
        print(200+(200*0.08)+60)
    else:
        print("We dont sell that")

if y: food(x,y)
else: food(x)
```

Testing:

```
n [140]: x = str(input())
     ...: y = str(input())
     ...:
     ...: def food(x,y = "Mohakhali"):
     ...:     if x == "BBQ Chicken Cheese Burger" and y == "Mohakhali":
     ...:         print(250+(250*0.08)+40)
     ...:     elif x == "BBQ Chicken Cheese Burger" and y != "Mohakhali":
     ...:         print(250+(250*0.08)+60)
     ...:     elif x =="Beef Burger" and y =="Mohakhali":
     ...:         print(170+(170*0.08)+40)
     ...:     elif x =="Beef Burger" and y !="Mohakhali": #for only Beef Burger function prints this.
     ...:         print(170+(170*0.08)+60)
     ...:     elif x =="Nana Drums" and y =="Mohakhali":
     ...:         print(200+(200*0.08)+40)
     ...:     elif x =="Nana Drums" and y !="Mohakhali":
     ...:         print(200+(200*0.08)+60)
     ...:     else:
     ...:         print("We dont sell that")
     ...:
     ...: if y: food(x,y)
     ...: else: food(x)
     ...:
Beef Burger

223.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as expected. You just need to understand how it's working.

1. Call the function like `food(x)`. It takes default value for `y`, which is `Mohakhali`

   Input `Beef Burger`, it'll return `223.6`
2. Call the function like `food(x, y)`. It takes value for `y`, even if you don't enter anything it doesn't match `Mohakhali`, so it'll return the next condition `y != "Mohakhali"`

   Input `Beef Burger` and then `Pallabi` or keep it blank, it'll return `243.6`

As you have two inputs in your code, it'll always expect two inputs from the user, no matter how you call your function, with one or two params.